# Can I use emails in the completion list from CTRL-P

Tags: autocompletion

When I press `<c-p>` for autocompletion a list based on my `complete` setting appears.  I have a completion file as follows (at `~/emails`)`:

```
barabara.high@someplace.com
john.doe@gmail.com
john.carpenter@ooo.ooo
```

But when I write (in insert mode) `joh` and press `<c-p>` only

```
john.doe
john.carpenter
```

Appear as the completions.  i.e. without the email domains.

---

My `iskeyword` and `complete` are as follows:

```
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,-,.,192-255
set complete=k~/emails
```

My `iskeyword` has `@` explicitly included, why does the completion list do not treat the entire email as a cword?

(`:expand('<cword>')` does not take the entire email as a cword either).

Comment: A while ago I wrote a [complete_email.vim](http://arp242.net/code/complete_email.vim/) plugin which allows completing emails from a file with `<C-x><C-m>` (or another mapping of your choice). It also adds the name (e.g. `"Example user" <foo@example.com>`) and shows the phone number (if entered).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Heh, to be really fair my "file" is the output of `abook --mut-query` (of which you are aware given that link :) ).  I just simplified it for MCVE reasons.  But yeah, that pointed me to an `abook` solution, thanks.

Comment: I have my own completion setup for using vim together with mutt. You can find it [here](https://www.256bit.org/~chrisbra/cms/vim_as_e-mail_editor.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format for `'iskeyword'` is explained at `:help 'isfname'`. In particular:

> To include '@' itself use "@-@".

`@` is shorthand meaning 'all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE'.